# Using Twitter OAuth for Single-User users/lookup API call

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I am trying to create an application in PHP that returns the json from the Twitter users/lookup API using OAuth.  I will only be using this as a single user.  I only need my credentials authenticated.

There are some good examples out there for posting tweets, but all I want to do is return the json for a call like the one below (using different values for the screen name parameter):

https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=twitterapi

Any Ideas?

Comment: You might have noticed that the URL you provided works without any sort of authentication.  Are you sure you need OAuth here?  (Disclaimer: I know nothing about the Twitter API other than it exists and uses OAuth.)

Comment: This particular call doesn't need authentication.  But Twitter recommends it.  Also, when this version of the API is shut off in a couple of months, the next version requires OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) use the [Dev Twitter OAuth API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/tokens-devtwittercom). It is recommended if:

> Your application only needs to make requests on behalf of a single
>   user

Comment: Looking for a complete example.  I have previously not had success with the twitter documentation.